# Solve integral weird upper bound approaching zero.

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve an integral of the form

$$p(0,t+\delta t)=\int_0^{\mu \delta t} f(x,t) dx$$

for $\delta t \rightarrow 0$

Intuitively, I would think that this integral has an upper bound which approaches the lower bound and therefore the result should be $f(0,t)$. However, this does not seem to be correct but I don't know how to approach the problem correctly. Has anybody a hint?

**Update:**

The result of this integral is supposed to be

$$ \mu f(0,t) $$

Unfortunately, I do not see how this is obtained.

Comment: I would think that this would result in a derivative of the function's antiderivative with respect to $t$...

Comment: is $\delta t$ somehow correlated to $t$?

Comment: It is actually the right hand side of a transition equation to calculate a state probability. So $\delta t$ is used to relate the state at time $t + \delta t$ to the state at time $t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to see if we get rid of some notation.

Replace $\delta t$ by the symbol $h$. Let $g(h)$ be the function

$$ g(h) = p(0,t+h) = p(0,t + \delta t) $$

Let $k(x) = f(x,t)$. (Notice that throughout the question, $t$ is an arbitrary, but unchanging variable, so we can suppress it from the notation.)

Then your question asks to find, as $h\to 0$, the quantity

$$ g(h) = \int_0^{\mu h} k(x) ~\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$

If $k(x)$ is bounded near $x = 0$ and integrable, then clearly

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = 0 $$

However, given the "expected answer", what you are after is more likely

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} $$

And given the more transparent form in equation (1), you see that by the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} = g'(0) = \mu k(0) $$

as desired.

The $\mu$ factor comes in as follows: let $K(s) = \int_0^s k(x) ~\mathrm{d}x$ be the antiderivative of $k$. Then we have

$$ g(h) = K(\mu h) $$

So the $\mu$ factor appears from the chain rule when taking derivatives of both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just wondering how I can justify to use the quotient $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)}{h} $$ since this would not be the way  to go when trying to integrate.

Comment: @Christoph: can you explain your comment more? My answer says that if you were to compute $\lim_{\delta t\to 0} p(0,t + \delta t)$ from your definition you would get $0$. The natural way to arrive at $\mu f(0,t)$ is from computing $\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \frac{p(0,t+\delta t)}{\delta t}$. In other words, what you want to get and what you were computing are two different things. If you are convinced that $\mu f(0,t)$ is the correct answer, then you need to tell us what exactly $\mu f(0,t)$ is  (what the answer represents) as well as what you want to compute (what you think the question is)

Comment: ... and only then can we answer you why you should compute $\lim_{h\to 0} g(h)/h$ instead of $\lim_{h\to 0} g(h)$.